# How to display keyphrases values in json via php

Tags: php

I have the following code and json data below.

I can successfully print the **products Id**.

**My issues** is how can I print or display all the **keyPhrases** values

Below is my effort so far

```
<?php

$output ='
{"documents":[{"product_id":"101","keyPhrases":["Product","Boy","girl","food","help","Nice"]}],"modelVersion":"2020-07-01"}
';
echo $output;


$json = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($json["documents"] as $row){

echo $product_id = $row["product_id"];
echo "<br><br>";

// printing keyphrases values having issues
echo $keyPhrases = $row["keyPhrases"];
echo "<br><br>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to add this to your code:

```
foreach($row["keyPhrases"] as $phrase)
        print_r("<br>$phrase<br>");
```

you need to notice that this line

```
echo $keyPhrases = $row["keyPhrases"];
```

gives a Notice : Notice: Array to string conversion, because  $row["keyPhrases"] is an array and not a string value.